# Emberjs Getting array property returns undefined

Tags: ember.js

I want to define a reactive array property in a component so that every time the array is updated, it auto-updates necessary HTML content.

I thought this was going to be straightforward, but it didn't work as I expected. Every time I retrieve the property via `this.get('array')`, it returns `undefined`.

```
// components/test-component.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  _array: [],

  array: Ember.computed('_array',{
    get(key) { return this.get('_array'); },
    set(key,value) { this.set('_array', value); }
  }),

  isEmpty: Ember.computed('array', function() {
    // Here, this.get('array') returns undefined. Why?
    return this.get('array').length;
  }),

  actions: {
    addNew() {
      this.get('array').push(Date.now());
    }
  },

  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);

    this.set('array', [1,2,3]);
  },
});
```

I also noticed that in the `init` method, if I retrieve the array property right after setting it, it also returns `undefined`. Why is this happening?

Here is a [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/303927e9f93fb6bd3f55a3d42706312b?openFiles=components.test-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.test-component.hbs). It is supposed to iterate the array, and show a list of all items, but it is currently crashing because it returns undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are currently seeing is that you need to add a `return` in the `set` method. Also you should use the `Ember.computed('array.[]')` syntax where you listen for changes to the array itself.

But you would be better off using an Ember array so that you don't need a second array:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  array: undefined,
  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.set('array', Ember.A());
  },
  actions: {
    addNew() {
      this.get('array').addObject(Date.now());
    }
  }
});
```

and

```
<ul>
  {{#each array as |item|}}
    <li>{{item}}</li>
  {{else}}
     <li>No items</li>
  {{/each}}
 </ul>
 <button onclick={{action 'addNew'}}>Add New</button>
```

Comment: You only ever need `Ember.A` if you have prototype extensions disabled.

Comment: @PatsyIssa does that mean that by default the native `Array` has it's prototype extended by Ember (in other words an `Array` object is an Ember array by default)?

Comment: Correct unless [ember-disable-prototype-extensions](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-disable-prototype-extensions) is installed.